# Date.gettime() is not a function, undefined

Tags: ios, date, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework

It is working on android and browser and WAS working on iOS (ionic view and device). I am saving a date inside my local Storage (`import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';`) then compare it to a another date

Here's what I do And is working everywhere but ***suddenly***, not ios under ionic view. Last test was maximum 2 weeks ago and was working as intended !

```
this.storage.get(filename).then((metadata_stored) => {
    if (metadata_stored && metadata_stored.date && metadata_stored.date.getTime() === filedate.getTime())
       //do something
```

and I get `TypeError: metadata_stored.date.getTime() is not a function; metadata_stored.date.getTime is undefined`.

filedate is create through something like this `filedate: Date = new date("2017-10-14T15:44:48+02:00")` (supposedly an ISO). Then it is saved in my local storage : `this.storage.set(filename, { /* ... */ , date: filedate })`

If I display metadata_stored.data, I get something like `2017-08-13T13:44:10.000Z`

I don't get why it suddenly and silently stopped working. And how to correct it since metadate.date is an old value of filedate and filedate is a `new Date(...)` ! No code were changed in this section last 2 weeks.

Edit: I solved it by doing `(new Date(metadata_stored.date)).getTime()` instead. But *I still have no idea why it stopped working* for no reason...

Answer (score 0):

In local storage, everything is stored as a string.

That means you *should* use `(new Date(metadata_stored.date)).getTime()` because `metadata_stored.date` is a `string`, not a `Date`.

```
let a = new Date();
let b = new Date();

// 2017-11-30T18:01:01457Z object
console.log(a, typeof a);
// 2017-11-30T18:01:01457Z object
console.log(b, typeof b);

localStorage.a = a;
localStorage.b = b;

a = localStorage.a;
b = localStorage.b;

// Thu Nov 30 18:01:01 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) string
console.log(a, typeof a);
// Thu Nov 30 18:01:01 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) string
console.log(b, typeof b);

a = new Date(localStorage.b);
b = new Date(localStorage.a);

// 2017-11-30T18:01:01457Z object
console.log(a, typeof a);
// 2017-11-30T18:01:01457Z object
console.log(b, typeof b);
```

Comment: Any idea why was it working before and why it has stopped working on iOS only ? ._.

Comment: There may have been a subtle change to type juggling (JavaScript is pretty good at forcing a type to be another type when you do a strange assignment like string to date) - or there might have been a change to the format string used in local storage for dates - or something else might have caused a problem, like it works on BST but not GMT.